# How to set the maximum date to the cupertino datepicker in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to set the maximum date of the datepicker of Cupertino Picker to current date So that users can not select a future date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pass a `maximumDate`

```
CupertinoDatePicker(..., maximumDate: DateTime.now())
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker/CupertinoDatePicker.html

Comment: not working. Still I can scroll the dates to future.

Comment: You can't chose one beyond that limit though as far as I know. I think there is an open issue about limiting which dates are shown as enabled/disabled.

Comment: I am able to choose the date beyond the maximumDate limit.

Comment: Hard to tell. Might be a bug in the widget.

Comment: The above works only  in case `mode` is set to `CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime`. This is very annoying, since I would like to use `CupertinoDatePickerMode.date`, however it is not possible. Basically, you cannot limit the picker to specific date in case your mode differs from the former mentioned.

Comment: @AngelTodorov I'd suggest you check if there is a feature request/bug report for this and if not, create one.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer - Actually, there is already filled in issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24820, however nobody is taking care of it as it seems...

Comment: Be careful if you are using `initialDateTime:  DateTime.now()` 

bacause the initial DateTime will be later in the future than                           `maximumDate:  DateTime.now(),` - either put the initial property before, or substract a couple of seconds of the initialDateTime or probably the best choice use the same variable to set these two values